# Highcharts multiple fill colors

Tags: javascript, jquery, colors, highcharts, fill

I'm trying figuring out how to put every other with a brigther fill color for the same serie.

Please have a look at my reference, this is what I want to accomplish.

```
http://imgur.com/sYW8guR
```

FYI: Heres a simple area chart to save you time

```
http://jsfiddle.net/kylander/33cutjqn/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a way to do this without either using multiple series, or writing your own complex rendering script.

Another alternative for using 2 series that works a little different than the one proposed by Sebastian:

1) User the alternateGridColor

2) set the fillColor of your series with an appropriate opacity for the alternate grid color to have the desired effect

3) use a 2nd series, which can be automatically created, to stack on top of the main data series, filled with white to cover the alternating color in the 'open' space.

`Example`:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/mg4vs1dm/

Honestly, I would personally simply opt to use the alternateGridColor option as is, however.

Answer (score 1):

The simples way is using two series. http://jsfiddle.net/sbochan/gba46s7L/

```
 series: [{
        name: 'USA',
        data: [1,2,3,2]
    }, {
        name: 'USSR/Russia',
        data: [null,2,3]
    }]
```

Comment: Almost! Whats the harder way? Since we're a analtyics company it will be to complex going with multiple series all the time.

Answer (score 1):

After playing a little bit with svg i found another solution to this.

Instead of defining color you may write

```
color: "url(#SomePattern)"
```

Define the pattern in separate svg like this

```
<div id="defs" style="width:0px;height:0px;">

    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" 
         xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

    <defs>
        <pattern id="SomePattern"
             width="50" height="50"
             patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">

             <rect width='50' height='50' fill='#BDDEE8'/>
             <rect x='25' width='25' height='50' fill='#D4E4E9'/>
        </pattern>
    </defs>
    </svg>
</div>
```

and then insert with something like

```
$(".highcharts-container defs").append($("#pattern-container defs").html());
```

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DrathVedro/33cutjqn/2/

However, it's just a texture and it's not bound to points like in your demo.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
xAxis.alternateGridColor
```

Docs:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.alternateGridColor

Comment: Its incorrect, because color need to be in series area, not entire chart.

Comment: Yeah but thats for filling the grid, I only want this on the series fill color.